# Type checking for array

Tags: javascript, typechecking, duck-typing

When I do: `typeof([])` it returns `object`.

I've heard its not really acceptable to edit the prototypes of JavaScript's inbuilt types.

However, if I do this: `Array.prototype.isArray = true;` and then the following work:

```
var arr = [];
var obj = {};

if (arr.isArray)
{
    console.log("Array");
}
else
{
    console.log("Not array");
}

if (obj.isArray) // undefined
{
    console.log("Array");
}
else
{
    console.log("Not array");
}
```

Or is this still not acceptable? What would be a better way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
yourThing.constructor === Array
```

This returns `true` if `yourThing` is an array.

So you don't have to change Array's prototype. [Modifying objects you don't own is widely seen as bad practice](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `instanceof` ([MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)) :

```
var arr = [];
if (arr instanceof Array) {
  console.log('this is an array');
}
```